# Get list of column names for columns that contain negative values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

This is a simple question but I have found "slicing" `DataFrames` in `Pandas` frustrating, coming from `R`.

I have a `DataFrame` `df` below with 7 columns:

```
df
Out[77]: 
     fld1  fld2  fld3  fld4  fld5  fld6  fld7
0     8     8    -1     2     1     7     4
1     6     6     1     7     5    -1     3
2     2     5     4     2     2     8     1
3    -1    -1     7     2     3     2     0
4     6     6     4     2     0     5     2
5    -1     5     7     1     5     8     2
6     7     1    -1     0     1     8     1
7     6     2     4     1     2     6     1
8     3     4     4     5     8    -1     4
9     4     4     3     7     7     4     5
```

How do I slice `df` in such a way that it produces a list of columns that contain at least one negative number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select them by building an appropriate Series and then using it to index into `df`:

```
>>> df < 0
    fld1   fld2   fld3   fld4   fld5   fld6   fld7
0  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False   True  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3   True   True  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
5   True  False  False  False  False  False  False
6  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False  False   True  False
9  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
>>> (df < 0).any()
fld1     True
fld2     True
fld3     True
fld4    False
fld5    False
fld6     True
fld7    False
dtype: bool
```

and then

```
>>> df.columns[(df < 0).any()]
Index(['fld1', 'fld2', 'fld3', 'fld6'], dtype='object')
```

or

```
>>> df.columns[(df < 0).any()].tolist()
['fld1', 'fld2', 'fld3', 'fld6']
```

depending on what data structure you want.  We can also use this io index into `df` directly:

```
>>> df.loc[:,(df < 0).any()]
   fld1  fld2  fld3  fld6
0     8     8    -1     7
1     6     6     1    -1
2     2     5     4     8
3    -1    -1     7     2
4     6     6     4     5
5    -1     5     7     8
6     7     1    -1     8
7     6     2     4     6
8     3     4     4    -1
9     4     4     3     4
```